# Why in this example did they wrap the response in another Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, promise

So I am looking at this code from https://javascript.info/promise-api.

```
let names = ['iliakan', 'remy', 'jeresig'];

let requests = names.map(name => fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}`));

Promise.all(requests)
  .then(responses => {
    // all responses are resolved successfully
    for(let response of responses) {
      alert(`${response.url}: ${response.status}`); // shows 200 for every url
    }

    return responses;
  })
  // map array of responses into an array of response.json() to read their content
  .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json())))
```

Why does the .then() pass the response to yet another Promise.all?

```
.then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json())))
```

I tried to simplify it to the code below but it just throws undefined error:

```
.then(responses => responses.map(r => r.json()))
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

`requests` is an array of promises and you want to iterate over them once they are all resolved.

> The `Promise.all()` method takes an iterable of promises as an input,
> and returns a single `Promise` that resolves to an array of the results
> of the input promises. This returned promise will resolve when all of
> the input's promises have resolved, or if the input iterable contains
> no promises. It rejects immediately upon any of the input promises
> rejecting or non-promises throwing an error, and will reject with this
> first rejection message / error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

The second `Promise.all` is acting on this array of promises:

```
Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.json())))
```

If they didn't use Promise.all here, then the promises would not be resolved in the next `then` call.

You could refactor the function so they are json'd from the start like so:

```
let names = ['iliakan', 'remy', 'jeresig'];

let requests = names.map(
  name => fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}`)
    .then(r=>r.json())
);

Promise.all(requests)
  .then(content => {
    // do something with content directly
  });
```

But then you wouldn't be able to log the `url` and `status` like they are.